# Table content extraction using paddleOCR

Tags: python, ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

Consider i already know the table structure which remains same across. when i get an image which includes picture of the table. I will do OCR (decided to go with Paddle OCR) and extract the text and put it in tables (for example how we do fill in the blanks).So how can i start with it? if anyone has references please share!

Tried with table detection but results were not good so want to go with this method